# Using SAML authentication within nginx

Tags: nginx, single-sign-on

I want to restrict access to some static content, served using nginx, using an existing SAML 2.0 IdP. (In Apache, this would be done with a module such as `mod_mellon` or `mod_auth_saml`)

What is the best way to use SAML authentication for static content on nginx? If it is still the use of [X-Accel headers](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxXSendfile), is there a helper script out there to proxy from a SAML authentication or do I need to start from scratch for this?

Comment: Anu possible option now with Openresty or nginx for SAML based authenication ?

Answer (score 2):

Someone or the shib project has a free SSO dynamic module for nginx.

https://github.com/nginx-shib/nginx-http-shibboleth

Answer (score 1):

You can try **auth-request** module as mentioned : [SSO with Nginx](https://developers.shopware.com/blog/2015/03/02/sso-with-nginx-authrequest-module/)

Answer (score 0):

It's 2017 now and there is still no module in nginx, no matter free or paid, to get SAML authentication.

I wouldn't expect it to be available anytime soon, considering it's been missing for almost a decade.

Comment: paid? https://kemptechnologies.com/load-balancing-nginx/single-sign-on-sso-nginx/

Comment: https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-saml