# Is there a way to add SAML-based SSO to an unauthenticated application I am hosting?

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, saml

I am running an application that doesn't have authentication built-in. I would like to require Google SSO with SAML as a way for users to be allowed to use the application. I am looking for any advice on how to achieve this. I have set up other applications with Google SSO/SAML, but they had configuration UIs built-in.

I did see [this Server Fault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/488334/using-saml-authentication-within-nginx); I am not familiar with Shibboleth, but it seems like it might be an option. Use a self-hosted Shibboleth application as a service provider configured in an nginx reverse-proxy in front of my application, and set up my Google IdP for authentication.

I am not 100% sure I am using the right terminology and if the potential solution makes sense but would appreciate ideas or advice or alternative ideas. Is this new question appropriate or should continue this discussion on [the older Server Fault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/488334/using-saml-authentication-within-nginx).

I am currently looking around search engines for ideas, but I also do not know the best search keywords to use.

Comment: You're def on the right track. You need a reverse proxy in front of your app, that can do SAML auth, and then configure your app to only allow connections from the reverse proxy.